# How to automate snackbar message which stays only for seconds using Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, contains, normalize-space

I have to automate highlighted "P" tag text.

Snapshot of the element:

[image]

I am trying with below code. But its not identifying the element.

```
ele = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//p[text()="Connection Tested Successfully"]')))
if ele:
    print("Pass")
else:
    print("Fail")
```

Output:

[image]

Another snapshot:

[image]

Any solution on this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text within the `<p>` tag i.e. *`Connection Tested Successfully`* contains leading and trailing space characters which you need to consider while constructing the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *`contains()`*:

  ```
  ele = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//p[contains(., "Connection Tested Successfully")]')))
  ```
- Using *`normalize-space()`*:

  ```
  ele = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//p[normalize-space() = "Connection Tested Successfully"]')))
  ```